# Trouble opening Ncurses Examples in OS X

Tags: configure, ncurses

I recently downloaded ncurses from  [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/) and have compiled it using `./configure` and `make`

As it is recommended in the README, I compiled the example programs that come bundled with the package. The programs compiled without any issue, but every time I run the programs I get the following errors:

`Terminal type "xterm-256color"
terminals database is inaccessible`
Changing the terminal's type using `TERM=xterm` and `export TERM` don't seem to solve this issue, and I'm just stuck. Will ncurses work if I included them in my C/C++ programs, or should I make sure the examples work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you did not install the terminal database, or did not tell the programs where to find it.

OSX comes with ncurses 5.7 (old, but not the problem here), with the terminal database in `/usr/share/terminfo`.  However by default the configure script assumes you want to install in `/usr/local`.  You can tell the programs where there's a terminal database by setting the `TERMINFO` environment variable, or (better), setting `TERMINFO_DIRS` to list both locations (with the newer one first of course).

For a start, something like

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

should be enough to make the examples run.

Further reading:

- [TERMINFO](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO)
- [TERMINFO_DIRS](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS)

Comment: This made the examples run. Thank you! I am a bit confused, though, do I need to do anything els to be able to use the ncurses libraries in C++ programs?

Comment: Setting the environment variable only helps for the shell where you set that.  I'd go ahead and install (into /usr/local, I assume) and set `TERMINFO_DIRS` to the two directories, e.g., /usr/local/share/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo